# What is the youtube-dl best format?

Tags: sound, youtube-dl, audacity

I'm downloading a video with youtube-dl and trying to get the best possible sound quality. Youtube-dl has an option **--audio-quality best** that is supposed to achieve that. As I would expect, that doesn't conflict with the **--x** option for extracting audio. But how do I play the audio back?  With **audacity**, I have to specify the format of the input.

Comment: It will automatically pick the best option. You can look at the available formats, and decide from there. But, a good media player, like VLC, should be able to read it automatically, without you having to specify

Comment: I also think it is `--audio-quality 0` for the best and `--audio-quality 10` for the worst.  Look at `youtube-dl --help`

Comment: Got a small app [here](https://launchpad.net/~jentiger-moratai/+archive/ubuntu/mediatools) with focus on best audio and video